# can't set margin-top in chrome on $(windows).load()

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

I tried to set with JQuery margin-top in chrome on page load.

```
$(window).load(function(){  

    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);


    if (isChrome) {
        //alert("You are using Chrome!");
        $('.footer_links').css("margin-top","0px;");
    }

    if (isSafari) {
        //alert("You are using Safari!");
        $('.footer_links').css("margin-top","10px;");
    }
```

with Safari it works good, but chrome fails. But when I want to change background color like:

```
$('.footer_links').css("background-color","red");
```

it works both Chrome and Safari.

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: remove ;  this from pxto be '0px' and '10px'

Comment: Why would you do that? why don't you just use `*{box-sizing:border-box}`

Comment: for users with same problem
    if (isChrome) {
    //alert("You are using Chrome!");
    $('.footer_links').css("marginTop","0px;");

    }

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$('.footer_links').css("margin-top", "0");
```

instead of

```
$('.footer_links').css("margin-top", "0px;");
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is `0px;`

write without   `px;`

Answer (score 0):

```
css("margin-top","0px;");
```

to

```
css("margin-top","0px");
```

and

```
css("margin-top","10px;");
```

to

```
css("margin-top","10px");
```

without `;`